# Links disabled in html

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I've been working on a revamp of the charity site I'm the webmaster for, heroinitiative.org. It is located here:
http://www.heroinitiative.org/revamp/default.html
(and no it's not live code, it sits alongside the live site just so I can show progress to my boss, it's not really important to keep it under wraps, which is why I can post it here)

My problem: For some reason all links in the footer (from id "bodyfooter" on down, including anything I put below the "Partners/Thanks" footer) have been disabled. I don't know why this is happening as I've thoroughly reviewed the code.

It happens in:
Firefox 3.6.8
Chrome 5.0.375.127 & 6.0.472.53 (just upgraded as I typed this)

but not in:
IE 8.0.7600.16385 (or in it's compatibility mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a `z-index:-1` on `#bodyfooter`. main.css line 182

remove this or change it to 0.

Comment: Ah yeah...that did it. Guess I need to find a different way to get the footer wrap to show. edit: ok, I figured out a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Your page takes a long time to display in Safari on my Mac.

Whenever I have a page that does not render as I expect, I run it through the [W3C Markup Validation Service.](http://validator.w3.org/)

Try fixing the errors displayed here:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heroinitiative.org%2Frevamp%2Fdefault.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Yeah I did that already, I started with 35 errors on it and took it down to what it is now. All the endif errors are due to the conditional css code for IE. I have no idea on the Byte-Order Mark...my first guess would be an invalid character but I have no idea how to find it.

Comment: I'd expect any decent editor to be able to display the BOM. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Using MS Expression Web 3...and I did find the option to add a BOM...it's under Page Editor Options->Authoring. This was enabled for most of the file types they listed, so I just disabled them.