# Links disabled in mobile version of website

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) as the template for this website, [www.ifgedmonton.org](http://www.ifgedmonton.org) Everything works fine on the desktop version, but in the mobile version, all links except the navigation don't work. I've run the code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=ifgedmonton.org), and fixed the possible candidates causing this issue. I've also looked at other suggestions regarding this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768690/twitter-bootstrap-modal-making-other-links-disabled), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654527/links-disabled-in-html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612582/bootstrap-navigation-links-not-working) and [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/text-links-not-working-from-mobile-devices)), but they don't work for me. To replicate, please open the website on a mobile device or make your browser window small enough for it to render the mobile version. The screenshot below shows which links I'm referring to.

[image: Links not working examples]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Solution

Change This

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="sidebar" role="navigation"></div>
```

To This

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" id="sidebar" role="navigation"></div>
```

This Will put your sidebar at the bottom

Or

Change it to this

```
<div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs" id="sidebar" role="navigation"></div>
```

This will hide your sidebar

Comment: I'm selecting this as the best answer. Thanks @DCdaz for your solution (which also works and might actually be a general solution for anyone looking in the future), but this answer fixes the actual problem with my code.

Answer (score 2):

Your Sidebar is overlapping your content because of this

`.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float:left;
}`

on your media queries for mobile use

`.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float:none;
}`

and youll be able to select ur text and links again

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Interestingly, I tried editing this line in the Bootstrap CSS, but that didn't fix it. I added this to my template directly in my custom styles section and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
<script src="http://www.ifgedmonton.org/assets/libs/boostrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

not pulling the file

check all of your links too bootstrap css and js files.

Comment: You're correct, that is an issue, but I don't think it's *the* issue stated in the question.

Comment: That will for sure help out if he's trying to use bootstrap. For sure part of his issue. @TimLewis

Comment: Don't worry, I'm agreeing with you. All I mean is there's **more** causing the specific issue in the question.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I fixed the link, had a typo, `boostrap`, instead of `bootstrap`! Nevertheless, the original issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it is not a mobile version. It is just getting squished. The right column when it drops below, breaks the links. I would look into getting a real mobile template. Here is a walkthrough: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-responsive-mobile-friendly-website-from-scratch-dive-into-the-code/

Answer (score 0):

You're sidebar div is sitting on top of you main content. You can fix this with the correct css, or add a clearing div between them.

```
<style>
    .clear { clear: both; }
</style>

<div class="clear"></div>
```